# How can a function parameter be used without mentioning it in the function body?

Tags: r

I've been trying to learn more about R (and writing C extensions) and I thought it might help to read the source for some well known packages.  I decided to start with rpart which is defined as:

```
rpart <- function(formula, data, weights, subset,
       na.action=na.rpart, method, model=FALSE, x=FALSE, y=TRUE,
       parms, control, cost, ...)
```

I did a quick search through the source and I don't see formula mentioned anywhere in the function body yet I know that somehow rpart is using that parameter.  How is it that rpart is using formula without its name being in the function body?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's pretty tricky:

```
m <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
# ...
m[[1L]] <- as.name("model.frame")
m <- eval(m, parent.frame())
```

The function uses `match.call` to find out how it is being called, modifies the call to replace the called function by `model.frame`, and calls it via `eval` with the parameters it received (although the part I replaced by `# ...` removes several of the parameters), and `model.frame` uses the `formula` parameter. See the documentation of `match.call`, `eval`, and `model.frame`, and experiment a little, e.g. try to understand what is happening here:

```
f <- function(formula, data) { 
  m <- match.call()
  m[[1L]] <- as.name('model.frame')
  eval(m, parent.frame())
}
f(x ~ y)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
x <- c(1,2,3)
f(x ~ y)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
y <- c(3,4,5)
f(x ~ y)
  x y
1 1 3
2 2 4
3 3 5
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2))
names(d) <- c('foo', 'bar')
f(foo ~ bar, d)
  foo bar
1   1   3
2   2   4
```